# windows phone 8 longlist selector .how to find the new item is added in the longlist selector.currently i am using ItemRealized event

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am currently using ItemRealized event to get the newly added item in the loglist selector but the problem is ,it fired during pageload .during pageload i added more than 20 items to list ,that time i don't want to fire itemrealized event.
 any other way equal to ItemRealized .or how to achieve this problem .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM pattern means You can Bind your `LongListSelector.ItemSource` to your ViewModel `ObservableColection<T>`.[ObservableColection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) implies [INotifyColectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) SO you will Get `ColectionChangedEvent`.